# Error occurred while loading the module of Microsoft.Online.SharePOint.PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

I was perfectly working with pnp-powershell then I planned to work with SP online management shell. I came across this error :

[image]

I have already tried installing the SPOL Management Shell. It says that package already exist. 
SO the problem is in importing this module only. Help appreciated!

Comment: open your powershell and type `set-executionpolicy unrestricted` and then close/open the powershell again. It should work

Comment: Thanks Gautam... so the problem was with ps execution policy ...I actually set the execution policy as remote signed then it worked.