# Microsoft Online Management Shell has no commands available

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

I installed the SharePoint Online Management Shell on two different Windows 10 machines. One worked fine, the other does not have any commands available. If I run get-module, it lists the Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.Powershell module, but the ExportedCommands field is blank. The version number displays the same version as the machine where this works. Apparently, there's some sort of conflict with another module I have installed?

The impact of this is that no commands function, including Connect-SPOService, which returns "the term 'connect-sposervice' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet..."

Any suggestions? I have already re-installed and rebooted. And yes, I'm running it as admin.

Comment: There would be a SharePoint online management shell in the start menu, search for it. You will find it there and then open it and run your commands inside it

Comment: That's what I did. Again, I did the exact same process on different machines. It works on one, not the other.

Comment: not 100% sure, but do you have admin rights on the machine ? It probably wont throw an error if you dont have admin rights. Can you install by right clicking and opening with Admin creds ?

Comment: Yes, I have admin rights. run as admin isn't an option when installing, but windows prompts for permissions

Comment: can you download [CSOM SPO SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=42038) and install it and then reinstall the SPO PowerShell and check ?

Comment: I uninstalled the SP online shell and the CSOM SPO SDK, reinstalled the SDK and then the shell. Same result. No error messages of any kind, but no exported commands.

Comment: Can you now try `Import-Module Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell -DisableNameChecking` and then test the connection with `Connect-SPOService`?

Comment: disable name caching didn't work either

Comment: If you open PowerShell ISE, do you see the SharePoint module in the list? If yes, can you open one command, click on "show details" and run it?

Comment: It does not appear in the ISE. (it does appear in the ISE on the working machine)

Comment: you mentioned about some module conflict that could be there, what module did you install ? Also, check if there is any "conflicting" SDK or PowerShell installation in your control panel > installed programs ! There could be some SP2013 module/SDK installed which might need to be uninstalled

Comment: The "conflicting module" was a guess. there are no errors or warning that I can find to confirm that. What other modules do I have? What don't I have? PNP, Exchange, Azure, Skype for Business, ShareGate. Each of these have probably been upgraded, installed, etc., multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

It is the SP powershell loading issue. I had the similar issue earlier and resolved it by setting the execution policy for power-shell for my fresh windows machine.

try this 
`set-executionpolicy -executionpolicy unrestricted`  Or `set-executionpolicy -executionpolicy remotelsigned`

then repoen the powershell and try the command Connect-SPOService etc.. It will work.

[Refer My Question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/243899/error-occurred-while-loading-the-module-of-microsoft-online-sharepoint-powershel)

**Edit1:** Try importing the module again from the .psd1 file for SPO management shell as

```
Import-Module 'C:\Program Files\SharePoint Online Management Shell\Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.P
owerShell' -verbose
```

and then check get-module. Refer my screen:
[image]

**Edit2:** If nothing works, sadly :( you may need to reinstall the windows

Comment: When I start of the SP online shell, no errors are displayed, so I don't think it's the same issue. Regardless, I changed the execution policy from remotesigned to unrestricted, with the same result. Cmdlets don't exist, and get-module shows the module with an empty value for exportedcommands.

Comment: If the Edit1 doesn,t work, then you may need to reinstall the windows as commented in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33082339/powershell-import-module-but-no-exportedcommands-available

Comment: running the import-module command with verbose shows "loading module from path", but never displays anything about importing cmdlets. There are no error messages.

Comment: Did you tried locating your .psd1 file in "C:\Program Files\SharePoint Online Management Shell\Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell"? verify its content. Also, try copying and replacing the DLLs and .psd1 from working windows machine to this new Machine. Then try Import command..

Comment: the psd1 file is there, and the contents are the same as on the working machine.

Comment: ohh.. Try copying and pasting all the contents of this folder from Working powershell machine to this Machine..  If this also doesn't work, uninstall this version of SPO management shell and try downgrading to older versions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79935/discussion-between-dvg-and-mike2500).

Comment: copying all files from the working machine to the problematic win 10 machine didn't work.

Comment: It seems Edit2 of my answer will do the magic. I know it ll be painful.. apologies